# How to make a query in the Postgress database asynchronously for testing in cypress?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, cypress

I am trying to get data from the database through an exported function. But the problem is that the function is returning empty data. The query works if executed outside the function, but when I put the query inside the function, the return is empty. I believe that the function is returning before the query gets the result from the database.

My code:

```
export function queryDb(query) {
    return new Promise(() => {
        database.select(database.raw(query).then(data => {
            return data;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
        })
        )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `resolve` and `reject` in your function

```js
export function queryDb(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        database.select(database.raw(query).then(data => {
            resolve(data);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
            reject(err)
        })
        )
    })
}
```

If you turn that into a [Custom Command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands), Cypress will await the resolve before moving on, which is handy to keep the sequence of things correct in the test.

```js
// cypress/support/commands.js

Cypress.Commands.add('queryDb', (query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        database.select(database.raw(query).then(data => {
            resolve(data);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
            reject(err)
        })
        )
    })
}

// in test

cy.queryDb(myQueryString).then(data => {
  // assert data is correct
})
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you!! I tested the solution in another project using only knex and it worked! But in cypress I am now getting this error: "this.driver.Client is not a constructor". 
I've tried to install typescript, pg and knex as super user to ensure the packages rightly installed, but no success.
Do you know anything about it? I'm putting the print screen in the following answer.

Comment: Actually, since it's querying a database I think you need a `cy.task` rather than a custom command. It uses the same pattern, except it runs in Node rather than the browser. I don't have experience with `postgresql`, but other databases require a connection is made first, then a query is sent. Both are handled in a task. Connection is made at the beginning of the spec file.